# Exception can't be handled?

Tags: java, exception

Eclipse keeps telling me I need to handle IOExceptions from the 1 following line of code.

If I add a catch for IOException it tells me that the catch block will never be reached, while at the same time it still tells me to handle IOExceptions for that same line of code.

If I change ReadEvents to throw Exception instead, it will keep telling me to catch Exception.

```
public static void SetEventURL(String url, boolean streamingMode) throws Exception {
try {
    Thread eventReadingThread = new Thread(() -> ReadEvents(url, streamingMode));
} catch (IOException e1) {
} catch (Exception e1) {
} catch (Throwable e1) {
}
```

**Why is it impossible to handle that line**?

Comment: Seems because the `IOException` can occur in the `ReadEvents` method, that's why eclipse tells you. But that method gets called inside the thread, so cannot be catched in the thread declaration. you need to catch it in the thread `run` method (which you are declaring as `ReadEvents`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the catch statement must be in the Thread code, inside the lambda expression.

Try this:

```
Thread eventReadingThread = new Thread(() -> {
    try{  ReadEvents(url, streamingMode); } catch (IOException e1) {}
});
```

Another (better) approach is to wrap `ReadEvents` (btw very bad name!) and catch `IOException` and then throw a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

Doing this you won't need to use any try/catch block inside the lambda.

On the other hand, if you need to handle exceptions thrown by another Thread, you should register an implementation of the interface `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

For instance:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {throw new RuntimeException("Hi!");});

    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, throwable) -> System.err.println("Error!"));

    t.start();//it'll print Error!
}
```